# How to manually import a module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

When i try to run ovirt downloads_disk_snapshot from this link i am getting error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download_disk_snapshots.py", line 22, in <module>
    import ovirtsdk4 as sdk
ImportError: No module named ovirtsdk4
```

Link is https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-engine-sdk/blob/master/sdk/examples/download_disk_snapshots.py

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) gives some very useful information on installing python packages.

In your case, you will have to install the oVirt Engine SDK itself before being able to run the example.

Installation instructions are given within the same Github project that you are mentioning:

https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-engine-sdk/blob/master/sdk/README.adoc#installation